# Make all other threads wait while executing a method with annoation @Scheduled in spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am having method load() which is scheduled to run for every 10min using spring @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100000) . This method will perform some actions to load huge data to my static list.

My main program uses this list to perform some logic. I want my main program to wait when load() is executing.

Can any one suggest how it can be done?

Comment: Where is your code ? Please follow SO guidelines for posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: fixedRate=100000 is not 10 minutes.